Django MySQL and CONVERT_TZ
I need to know the duration of some events in my MySQL database. Around DST the duration in UTC is different then in local time and I need to know them in local time.
I have found a way to do this, but I was wondering if this function can be improved.
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, fields
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL


duree = ExpressionWrapper(F('_dtend') - F('_dtstart'), output_field=fields.DurationField())

event_dur = Event.objects.annotate(
    _dtstart=Cast(
        RawSQL("CONVERT_TZ(dtstart, 'UTC', timezone)", ()), fields.DateTimeField()
    ),
    _dtend=Cast(RawSQL("CONVERT_TZ(dtend, 'UTC',timezone)", ()), fields.DateTimeField()),
).annotate(
    dur=duree
)

Without the convert_tz I find 8000 events, with only 1000. There are probably 7000 events around DST last October.
So the duration works fine. Great. Problem solved. However, if I do:
event_dur.first()._dtstart, event_dur.first().dtstart

I get back:
datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

As you can see the _dtstart (which uses Europe/Amsterdam btw) has the correct time, but the tzinfo is wrong (should be 'Europe/Amsterdam'). While for the duration this is no big problem I was wondering if there is a way to also include the correct timezone information directly out of the database?
